# TcpClient.Connect() - how do I control the error when an IP does not respond to me?

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp, visual-studio-2019

I have the code but in the fourth line I get the error since the IP does not respond.

When the first IP or any other does not respond the program stops, I need that if an IP does not respond to skip it and continue with the list until it is finished.

Displayed message:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not respond correctly after a period of time, or the established connection failed because the connected host did not respond 10.212.xxx.xx:88xx.

```
For p = 0 To UBound(ServerAddress)
    ClientSocket(p) = New TcpClient
    ClientSocket(p).ReceiveTimeout = 10000
    ClientSocket(p).Connect(ServerAddress(p), PortNumber)
Next
```

Comment: Could you wrap the Connect line in a try catch and deal with the error?

Comment: @AndrewMortimer This is the message on the try catch: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not respond correctly after a period of time, or the established connection failed because the connected host did not respond 10.212.xxx.xx:88xx.I'm debugging and here this line is the error.: ClientSocket(p).Connect(ServerAddress(p), PortNumber)

Comment: @Manny that is simply the debugger displaying the original error. Perfectly normal. Outside of the debugger, the `try/catch` can swallow the error, then you can move on.

Comment: @RemyLebeau okey, good after the try/catch, the next line is ServerStream = ClientSocket(p).GetStream() and the error message says: The operation is not allowed on non-connected sockets.

Comment: @Manny well, obviously, if an error occurs, you would have to skip your subsequent logic for that failing socket and move on to the next one

Answer (score 1):

Simply wrap the `Connect()` call in a [Try/Catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement) block:

```vb
For p = 0 To UBound(ServerAddress)
    ClientSocket(p) = New TcpClient
    ClientSocket(p).ReceiveTimeout = 10000
    Try
        ClientSocket(p).Connect(ServerAddress(p), PortNumber)
        ' use connection as needed...
    Catch
        ' error handling as needed...
    End Try
Next
```